# Weird issue with jQueryUI modal

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm having a weird issue with the jQueryUI modal (the dialog plugin that can include modal functionality). I have a dropdown list with a modal on one of the options. Now, the modal opens up just fine, however there are some strange errors. The link in the dropdown list to pop up the modal somehow gets inside the modal, with extra classes (I assume from the modal), and when the modal is closed, it disappears from the dropdown list. Finally, even though I put text in the modal, it doesn't show up. Here is the HTML portion:

```
<span class="dropdown" id="loggedInDropdown">
                        <i class="spriteIcons iconArrowUp"></i>
                        <ul class="zebraRows">
                            <li><a id="accountSettings" href="/stuff/settings" title="">Account Settings</a></li>
                            <li><a id="addFunds" class="no-close" href="" title="Add Funds to Your Account">Add Funds</a></li>
                            <li><a id="signOut" href="/users/logout" title="">Sign Out</a></li>
                        </ul> 
                    </span>
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
$('#loggedInDropdown').on('click', '#addFunds', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#addFunds').dialog({
            modal: true,
            text: 'Whatever'
        });
    });
```

Comment: By the way, I tried to do a JSFiddle of the code, but it seems to not have jQueryUI as a library.

Comment: JsFiddle has JQuery as a library... just look on the left side on the "Frameworks & Extensions" section... You can also add a library as an external dependency by the way...

Comment: Could you please do this. update href with href="#" as it might mess up your html. Besides try not to enclose your modal handler inside another handler. what happens if your move your modal handler out of the first handler?

Comment: I need it inside the other handler, as I want it to load when the user clicks that link, and I don't think that's possible without putting it inside the handler. By the way, I tried putting a "#", but it didn't help.

Comment: Can you put your modal HTML as well?

Comment: What modal HTML? I put everything that is related to the modal. I don't know what "modal HTML" you could be referring to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why Shamoon had been asking about the modal `html`, is because normally you'd point it elsewhere. For instance: **Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/NbBgW/5/

```
<span class="dropdown" id="loggedInDropdown">
    <i class="spriteIcons iconArrowUp"></i>
    <ul class="zebraRows">
         <li>
             <a id="accountSettings" href="/stuff/settings">
                 Account Settings
             </a>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a id="addFunds" class="no-close">
                Add Funds
            </a>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a id="signOut" href="/users/logout">
               Sign Out
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- The Container hiding the actual modal content -->
    <div id="hidden-container" style="display:none;">
        <!-- The Modal content -->
        <div id="addfunds-modal">
            Whatever .. Dude!
        </div>
    </div>

</span>
```

Then for the JavaScript:

```
<script>
   /**
    *   I've also changed it to:
    *   $(document).on('click' .. 
    *
    *   because with a Javascript page that has
    *   lots of changing elements, it's better off
    *   listening to the DOM Document itself.
   **/
   $(document).on('click', '#loggedInDropdown #addFunds', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#addfunds-modal').dialog({
          modal: true
      });
   });
</script>
```

Your Modal was *working* - but halfway,

There is no [`text:""`](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/) option for content, thus defaulting to itself (Itself being the target `html` for the `.dialog()` also). There is however a `text` option for buttons:

```
   .dialog({ 
       buttons: [{ 
            text: "Ok", 
            click: function() {
               //Code..
            } 
          }] 
       });
```

Comment: Thanks, I was confused about that. The docs don't say anything about loading a modal onclick, so I searched elsewhere, and I found something, but it looked like both said different things. The docs had a text element in the dialog, but the other thing didn't, which confused me more.

Comment: No worries! That's what SO is here for :D Alas though, there's __alot__ of different plugins & methods to doing the same thing with something like this out there; let alone different versions of jQuery & jQuery UI.

Comment: What I found was an SO question that explained how to load a jQueryUI modal with onclick, not another plugin. I definitely get your point, though.

Answer (score 1):

Your modal probably also has an id of `addFunds`. Change one of them for it to do what you want. I suggest changing the `<a>` tag's ID to be something like `addFundsLink`.

You'll also have to change the JavaScript to:

```
$('#loggedInDropdown').on('click', '#addFundsLink', function(e) {
```

Comment: I don't think the modal has an ID of its own. If it does, it's probably some weird jQuery name. Either way, changing the name of the `<a>` tag didn't help.

Comment: You were right, in a way, but you could've explained it a little better. I'll upvote you anyway, for effort.